# elasticsearch getting indices onto different server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index already on one server I want to move it to a different one without going through bulk indexing or whatever, the indices already exist. What's an easy way to move the indices? There should be some sort of import or some binary that could be copied. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use snapshot and restore:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html